# Delphi - TFDQuery - How To set updateStatus usUnmodified only for one record without revert it?

Tags: delphi

I would like to remove from TFDQuery.Delta, only one specific usModified record, but not reverting it. The same as TFDQuery.CommitUpdates but not to all DataSet, only for one choosed record. Anyone knows one easy way ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
FDQuery.GetRow.AcceptChanges;
```

This CommitUpdates only to current record on Local TFDDataSet.